# Find records which assoicated records do not belong to certain record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my system I have a following structure:

```
class Worker
  has_many :worker_memberships
end

class WorkerMembership
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event
  has_many :worker_memberships
end
```

Imagine I have a certain `@event`. How can I find all `workers` that have NO `worker_memberships` belonging to this `@event`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much synthesis of both other answers.

First: stick to `has_many through` as @TheChamp suggests. You're probably using it already, just forgot to write it, otherwise it just wouldn't work. Well, you've been warned.

I generally do my best to avoid raw SQL in my queries whatsoever. The hint about `select` I provided above produces a working solution, but does some unneessary stuff, such as `join` when there's no practical need for it. So, let's avoid poking an association. Not this time.

Here comes the reason why I prefer `has_many through` to `has_and_belongs_to_many` in many-to-many associations: we can query the join model itself without raw SQL:

```
WorkerMembership.select(:worker_id).where(event: @event)
```

It's not the result yet, but it gets us the list of `worker_id`s we don't want. Then we just wrap this query into a "give me all but these guys":

```
Worker.where.not(id: <...> )
```

So the final query is:

```
Worker.where.not(id: WorkerMembership.select(:worker_id).where(event: @event) )
```

And it outputs a single query (on `@event` with `id` equal to `1`):

```
SELECT `workers`.* FROM `workers` WHERE (`workers`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `worker_memberships`.`worker_id` FROM `worker_memberships` WHERE `worker_memberships`.`event_id` = 1))
```

I also give credit to @apneadiving for his solution and a hint about `mysql2`'s `explain`. SQLite's `explain` is horrible! My solution, if I read the `explain`'s result correctly, is as performant as @apneadiving's.

@TheChamp also provided performance costs for all answers' queries. Check out the comments for a comparison.

Comment: would you mind sharing the costs of both? just curiosity

Comment: @apneadiving sure thing: http://pastebin.com/BupHkLQf (be sure to turn text wrapping off, `explain` tables are long)

Comment: oh, shame mysql2 doesnt provide the cost :(

Comment: D-side: `Seq Scan on workers  (cost=27.52..39.27 rows=70 width=551)`

Comment: TheChamp: `Seq Scan on workers  (cost=53.63..65.38 rows=70 width=551)`

Comment: apneadiving: `Hash Anti Join  (cost=27.59..40.13 rows=70 width=551)`

Comment: So both are faster than mine, but not as readable. @D-side your solution is fast and somewhat readable :)

Comment: Nice work, @TheChamp! Like I said, it's synthesis of good parts of both :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Worker.where(WorkerMembership.where("workers.id = worker_memberships.worker_id").where("worker_memberships.event_i = ?", @event.id).exists.not)
```

---

Or shorter and reusable:

```
class WorkerMembership
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :event

  scope :event, ->(event){ where(event_id: event.id) }
end

 Worker.where(WorkerMembership.where("workers.id = worker_memberships.worker_id").event(@event.id).exists.not)
```

(I assumed table and column names from conventions)

Comment: I'd suggest you try all solutions but append them with `.explain`. This way you'll see the db cost. Then, I strongly advise you to select the lowest

Comment: thanks for pointing towards the `explain` method. I'd be interested what you think about the results. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64000/explain-activerecord-db-queries

Comment: Actually, on a nearly empty table this query complains about lack of `first` in `nil` and fails with a long stacktrace.

Comment: @D-side no idea what you did, but it's production code

Comment: @apneadiving clean Rails app, just these 3 models and the specified association, tables populated with 1 row each, linked. So this should return empty set of rows, but instead...

Comment: @D-side what db do you use?

Comment: @apneadiving SQLite, but it fails to build the query, it's probably irrelevant.

Comment: @D-side I think active record adapters try to adapt and sqlite is not meant to accept real queries

Comment: @apneadiving same on MySQL, just set it up to check. Can't be a coincidence. In both cases it outputs an object that "doesn't support `#inspect`" (says IRB) and when I try to `explain` it, it raises an error. Provide an example of generated SQL maybe?

Comment: @D-side from my app: `Notification.global.where(JoiningTables::EntityNotification.where("notifications.id = jt_entity_notifications.notification_id").for_entity(23).read(true).exists.not)
  Notification Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE "notifications"."category" = 1 AND (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT "jt_entity_notifications".* FROM "jt_entity_notifications"  WHERE (notifications.id = jt_entity_notifications.notification_id) AND "jt_entity_notifications"."entity_id" = 23 AND "jt_entity_notifications"."is_read" = 't')))`

Comment: Tried to poke randomly about your code. Got it working by making an odd change: `event_id: @event.id` to `event: @event`. This produces: ``SELECT `workers`.* FROM `workers` WHERE (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT `worker_memberships`.* FROM `worker_memberships` WHERE (workers.id = worker_memberships.worker_id) AND `worker_memberships`.`event_id` = 1))`` ...and seems to work okay. But now `explain` on that query fails. Odd. Investigating.

Comment: I think I understand, what if you do: `Worker.where(WorkerMembership.where("workers.id = worker_memberships.worker_id").where("worker_memberships.event_id = ?", @event.id).exists.not)`

Comment: Seems to work as well, but still can't `explain`: ``undefined method `explain' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter:...>``

Comment: @D-side dont know, should be ok for adapters sqlite3, mysql2, and postgresql.

Comment: @D-side actually I dont understand why you have an `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter` and not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: @apneadiving I am surprised as well, but you pointed out the cause, and, gosh, that was dumb `._.` That was `mysql` gem instead of `mysql2`. And I just figured out a simpler solution. Wow. Thanks.

Comment: @D-side simpler solution than? and thanks are even better with + 1 :)

Comment: @apneadiving a simpler query than yours, seems to do about the same, at least `explain` outputs are really similar.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to set up a many to many relationship between `Worker` and `Event`, I'd suggest you use the [through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Your resulting models would be.

```
class Worker
  has_many :worker_memberships
  has_many :events, :through => :worker_memberships
end

class WorkerMembership
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event
  has_many :worker_memberships
  has_many :workers, :through => :worker_memberships
end
```

Now you can just call `@event.workers` to get all the workers associated to the event.

To find all workers that *don't* belong to the `@event` you can use:

```
# get all the id's of workers associated to the event
@worker_ids = @event.workers.select(:id)

# get all workers except the ones belonging to the event
Worker.where.not(:id => @worker_ids)
```

The one-liner

```
Worker.where.not(:id => @event.workers.select(:id))
```

Comment: yes but no need to do 2 db queries, though benchmarks are not that clear

Comment: @apneadiving replacing `pluck` with `select` will do this, utilizing subqueries. Like `Worker.where.not(id: @event.workers.select(:id))`

Comment: Some internals on this: `pluck` forms a Ruby array and is mostly useful  for "plucking" **already loaded data** to get something specific. When you use it, it will have to be executed and become an array that AR will use to construct a condition. It lists all `id`s in array explicitly inside the main query. On especially large tables it might get insanely long statements. I never got this to break, but I've never had tables **that** large X)

Comment: FYI, the cost of this query is very high, I'd avoid this

Comment: @apneadiving there is a way to get `worker_id`'s without poking an association, by querying the join model itself. One minute...

Comment: @TheChamp of your whole query

Comment: @D-side did you check my solution?